# React Native - No command found with name 'focus'

Tags: react-native

I run the react-native app in my Xcode, it can be build succeeded, but when I click the Textinput of the login page , it throwed a error :

```
No command found with name "focus"

-[RCTUIManager dispatchViewManagerCommand:commandID:commandArgs:]
    RCTUIManager.m:1115
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

I search all of the questions ,but none can solve this problem.what's the reason of this error?

Comment: Please add your TextInput code here.

Comment: Same issue here after upgrading to react native 0.63.2

Comment: Same issue with scrollTo

React Native - No command found with name 'scrollTo'

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Check wether you're using react-native-reanimated@2.*.* Issue reported here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2364#issuecomment-916795999